# Why does IE try to print infinite pages?

Tags: internet-explorer, printing, print-preview

When I hit "Print Preview" on IE, if it is set to "Shrink to Fit" then infinite pages start getting added to the total pages. It starts with `Page 1 of 1` and rapidly increases the second number at a rate of about 100 per 10 seconds, but it slows down. Right now it says `Page 1 of 1272` and is increasing about three times a second, no sign of stopping.

If I change it to 100% instead of "Shrink To Fit" then it immediately has `1 of 2` and stays there.

How do I begin to debug this? It only happens on this one page. I'm unable to reproduce it on jsFiddle or anywhere else since it's a very complicated site.

Comment: This may be related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434727/ie11-printing-infinite-pages

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Quirks mode, there is a bug in IE9+ that causes expressions such as the one below

```
expression(body.clientHeight - this.offsetTop)
```

to infinite loop because it's miscalculating the clientHeight by 1px. It then continues to increase in size. Note: I've seen the this happen only sporadically.

Either way, to debug this, I would disable all the CSS and see if that fixes the problem with an un-styled page then add bits and pieces.